# Use native keypad or custom one in web application

Tags: web-app, input-fields, password, keypad

I'm tasked to implement a code entry view which allows you to enter a 6-digit code. The UI runs in the browser (JS/HTML/CSS), mobile touch devices only.

I'm stuck on how to implement this, basically I came up with these two scenarios:

**Use the native built-in keypad**

- (+) Built-in, accessibility
- (-) Requires an initial tap to trigger the keypad
- (-) Requires at least one "invisible" `<input>` tag
- (-) Handle "zoom-in" on the input field so that all digits are visible
- (-) Handle blinking cursor alignment with digits or use six separate input boxes with proper alignment and switch focus after each entered digit.
- (-) Relies heavily on how device handles/renders input fields.

**Use a custom HTML/JS keyboard, basically a grid of buttons**

- (-) Accessibility
- (-) Keypad needs to fit on screen on every device
- (+) No initial tap required to trigger a keypad
- (+) Consistent look and feel

What are your thoughts about this?

[image: Code entry view]

Comment: I'm not convinced it needs the initial tap to trigger it; I've got several programs where the keypad automatically pops up when the entry is required - and somehow, the app knows whether to pop up a numeric pad or a typewriter pad.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I know this can be done on native apps, but for a website an initial user interaction is required to allow focusing a text field.

Comment: Still not convinced; I'm pretty sure I've seen it where the web page has an `onload()` or `ongotfocus()` event defined. Or something like that; I'm not a web programmer, so I don't have the event method names memorized.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I made an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/st5dg76g/1/embedded/result/ it focuses on Desktop browsers, but on my iPhone it does not.

Comment: Interesting, and duplicated on my job iPhone, and my personal Android phone.

Answer (score 1):

There's really three issues here...

- **Accessibility**: Either approach can be just as accessible and just as easy to implement depending on who you plan on making the app accessible for. If this is only for mobile touch devices, **what matters is that elements are scaled properly so people don't mistakenly press the wrong button**.
- **Interaction Cost**: Extra click? Is that click *meaningful*? If so, keep that click. However, is there anything else the user would do other than enter in numbers? If not, then build a screen that has those inputs there already. **You create steps in a process to allow users to make meaningful decisions** (or to inform them what just happened or is about to happen). If that decision is largely *redundant*, automate it. Design screens with a prominent call-to-action that are blatantly waiting for that crucial decision.
- **Cross-Device Support**: Don't rely on an operating system or browser to do things precisely how you want them to. If you really want something to work *just-so*, you're rolling your own solution. With **flexbox** and **vh/vw CSS units** it's now very easy - and even without those it's still easy - to create a layout that adjusts to any screen. **If you want to establish a brand,  define interactions meticulously**.

So, with that, **I would say option 2 is the way to go**. Native UIs are inconsistent and add interaction cost. Your own solution will behave exactly as you want it to, and if you do that right, your users will be delighted.